# geopandas: from a column of coordinate list to geometry

Tags: list, geometry, geopandas

I have a DataFrame which has a column of coordinates list looks like the following:

[image]

I want to make this DataFrame a GeoPandas DataFrame with a `geometry` column. One way for doing this is to create two lists representing latitude and longitude and store the first and second element from the `coors` column to latitude and longitude, respectively. Then sue `gpd.points_from_xy` to build the geometry column. But this approach adds extra steps for building GeoPandas DataFrame. **My question is how to build `geometry` directly from the `coors` list**.

I add some test data here:

```
import pandas ad pd
import geopandas as gpd

data = {'id':[0,1,2,3], 'coors':[[41,-80],[40,-76],[35,-70],[35,-87]]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just apply `Point` to the `'coors'` column to generate point geometry.

```py
from shapely.geometry import Point

df['geometry'] = df.coors.apply(Point)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df)  # you should also specify CRS
```

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In the case that you have latitude and longitude in separated columns, You can do this:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point

def create_geometry(row):
  row["geometry"] = Point(row["latitude"],row["longitude"])
  return row

df = pd.read_[parquet|csv|etc]("file")
df = df.apply(create_geometry,axis=1)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df,crs=4326)
```

Then, You can verify it doing:

```
df.geometry.head(1)
```

output

```
16    POINT (7.88507 -76.63130)
Name: geometry, dtype: geometry
```